# JQuery advanced input mask to format and mask valid BYTE sequence "10 FE BA 59 6F"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement masked input which allows to input bytes, for example `10 FE BA 59 6F`, I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('input').mask("ZZ", {
    translation: {
      Z: { pattern: /[0-9a-fA-F]{1,2}\s*/, optional: true, recursive: true}
    },
    maxlength: false
  });
});
```

But it just doesn't allow to type anything.

What do I want: when user writes `10FEBA596F` input value becomes `10 FE BA 59 6F`, i.e. it inserts a space after each byte typed.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Please have a look below for the `byte mask` you requested and check :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look below for the `byte mask` you requested.

> As the masking `translation` pattern won't support inserting a `space`
>   and no `recursive` masking pattern supported there at the moment, I
>   have to override the `keypress` event in the masking options to achieve this.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.bitMask = function() {
      var applyMask = function() {
        var maskPattern = 'ZZ ';
        var mask = '';
        var valueToMask = $(this).val();
        var patternRepeatCount = Math.ceil(valueToMask.length / maskPattern.length);
    
        for(var i = 0; i < patternRepeatCount; i++) {
           mask += maskPattern;
        }

        mask += maskPattern;
      
        var option = { translation: {
           'Z': { pattern: /[0-9a-fA-F]/}
        }};
        
        var pseudoElm = $('<input type="text"/>');
        pseudoElm.val(valueToMask);
        pseudoElm.mask(mask, option);
        $(this).val(pseudoElm.val());
    };
    
    $(this).each(function() {
      var self = $(this);
      self.on('keypress', function() {
        setTimeout(applyMask.bind(this), 1);
      });
      
      self.on('paste', function() {
        setTimeout(applyMask.bind(this), 1);
      });
      
    });
  };
    

  $('input').bitMask();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: I changed code a bit (for example JS already has `.repeat` method on `string` type :) ), but your idea is great, thank you.

Comment: You can have a paste event. I will update the code shortly.

Comment: I checked documentation, it only provides 4 events, `onChange`,`onKeyPress`, `onComplete` and `onInvalid` which are only called when mask is already applied and value is trimmed

Comment: The main problem is when you have initial mask `ZZ ` for example and you are pasint `56 FB`, you get only `56 ` in all events, `FB` is trimmed and there is no way to find out what value originally was pasted.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Yeah, I got it and trying a nice way to fix this. Let me update the code shortly.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I have updated the code, please have a look.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I have updated another bit. Please take the latest.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'l check it in several hours (my PC is inaccessible right now)